# Connect camera to animation

Tags: animation, parent

I have an animation of model what is running on the spot. I copied keyframes and made it run all the time while the camera is moving. But I needed to make my character move the same distance as the camera does. I did it before with ctrl+p -> Make parent -> object, but it didn't work with this animation. 
What can I do? Thank you in advance[image]

Comment: Change the parent type to bone and set the camera as a child of a bone for example the hip.

Comment: Error: no active bone...

Comment: try it in the object properties tab: https://imgur.com/a/RfXJLAz

Comment: Ok, I got it. I chose head as parent bone and now the camera looks right to the head of the armature. I am confused

Comment: You can move the camera after the parenting. Then it will follow its parent.

Comment: Thanks a lot! .